# Inno Setup: Preview component on extra window

Tags: components, inno-setup, preview

How can I modify Inno Setup script from [Inno Setup: Enlarge component page only with preview and description](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40616922/850848) to on an separate window (512x400 dimensions).

Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building upon [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10867087/850848#37796528) to [Long descriptions on Inno Setup components](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10867087/850848). You will need to copy `HoverTimerProc` and it's supporting functions and global variables.

This answer modifies the `HoverComponentChanged` and `InitializeWizard` procedures to support an image window in addition to description labels.

```pascal
[Files]
...
Source: Main.bmp; Flags: dontcopy
Source: Additional.bmp; Flags: dontcopy
Source: Help.bmp; Flags: dontcopy

[Code]

var
  CompLabel: TLabel;
  CompForm: TSetupForm;
  CompImage: TBitmapImage;
  LoadingImage: Boolean;

procedure HoverComponentChanged(Index: Integer);
var 
  Description: string;
  Image: string;
  ImagePath: string;
begin
  case Index of
    0: begin Description := 'This is the description of Main Files'; Image := 'main.bmp'; end;
    1: begin Description := 'This is the description of Additional Files'; Image := 'additional.bmp'; end;
    2: begin Description := 'This is the description of Help Files'; Image := 'help.bmp'; end;
  else
    Description := 'Move your mouse over a component to see its description.';
  end;
  CompLabel.Caption := Description;

  if Image <> '' then
  begin
    { The ExtractTemporaryFile pumps the message queue, prevent recursion }
    if not LoadingImage then
    begin
      LoadingImage := True;
      try
        ImagePath := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\' + Image);
        if not FileExists(ImagePath) then
        begin
          ExtractTemporaryFile(Image);
        end;
        CompImage.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(ImagePath);
      finally
        LoadingImage := False;
      end;
    end;
    CompForm.Left := WizardForm.Left + WizardForm.Width;
    CompForm.Top := WizardForm.Top;
    CompForm.Visible := True;
  end
    else
  begin
    CompForm.Visible := False;
  end;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
var
  HoverTimerCallback: LongWord;
begin
  HoverTimerCallback := WrapTimerProc(@HoverTimerProc, 4);

  SetTimer(0, 0, 50, HoverTimerCallback);

  CompLabel := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
  CompLabel.Parent := WizardForm.SelectComponentsPage;
  CompLabel.Left := WizardForm.ComponentsList.Left;
  CompLabel.Width := WizardForm.ComponentsList.Width;
  CompLabel.Height := ScaleY(32);
  CompLabel.Top := WizardForm.ComponentsList.Top + WizardForm.ComponentsList.Height - CompLabel.Height;
  CompLabel.AutoSize := False;
  CompLabel.WordWrap := True;

  CompForm := CreateCustomForm;
  CompForm.ClientWidth := 512;
  CompForm.ClientHeight := 400;
  CompImage := TBitmapImage.Create(CompForm);
  CompImage.Parent := CompForm;
  CompImage.Top := 0;
  CompImage.Left := 0;
  CompImage.Width := CompForm.ClientWidth;
  CompImage.Height := CompForm.ClientHeight;

  WizardForm.ComponentsList.Height := WizardForm.ComponentsList.Height - CompLabel.Height - ScaleY(8);
end;
```

[image: Component preview window]

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, How to display localized images? (eng, spa). My images contain some text. I have to create a new question?

Comment: @NicoZ One way is to define a "custom message" with a name of the image file. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/31053177/850848 - If you need more details, ask a question.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, I'm trying to change the color of the description of the ¨Additional Files¨ only. How to change the color only of that?

Comment: @NicoZ That's definitely a new question.